# PHP: If address contains snippet, replace image on page w/ another image

Tags: javascript, php

I have several pages generated by PHP that contain this image:

```
rectangle21_19.png
```

Each of these pages has this snippet in their URL:

```
name=NEWBERRY
```

I'm looking for a way in PHP that takes any page w/ the `name=NEWBERRY` snippet, and replaces the aforementioned image with this image:

```
hex10_11.png
```

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_GET[name]=="NEWBERRY"){
    echo "<script>
          var oldimg = 'rectangle21_19.png';
          var newing = 'hex10_11.png';
          $('img[src=\"' + oldimg + '\"]').attr('src', newimg);
         </script>";
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't replace any mention of `rectangle21_19.png` with `hex10_11.png`, which is what I was shooting for.